# After my Pi boot and enters the desktop, the screen turns blank moments later

Tags: hdmi, display

My Pi used to work fine. Now every time I turn it on, the screen turns black right after I get a glimpse of the desktop. However, the screen does not enter sleep. The Pi is connected via hdmi to a dvi monitor using a converter.

Comment: If there is a regular HDMI screen somewhere within a few miles you can test with for a minute, you can at least rule out the converter cable...

Comment: It used to work perfectly with the same cable. Also, when it is booting, I see the checks and the boot process. I even see a flash of the desktop before it goes black.

Comment: No, not being sarcastic. I don't know anyone with an hdmi monitor. I do, however, realize my mistake in dismissing your suggestion without even trying it.

Comment: Are you Runing any cpu intensive applications, or any new sub devices and have you attempted to change the power supply that you are using for your Pi?, as the Pi may no longer be supplying enough power to power the dvi adapter